# Update Data to appropriate Column and row in excel from one sheet to another in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

As I mentioned in the title, I need to copy Data from one Sheet to another.I have the same data (not in the same order) in both sheets. I want to update data in the 1st sheet as the corresponding row in 2nd one changed. For example I have in the First sheet:

```
A   B           C 
1   one         1.1
2   two         1.2
3   three       1.3
4   one + two   2.3
5   one + three  ??
```

and in the 2nd one:

```
A   B          C 
1   one        1.1
2   two        1.2
3   three      1.3
```

As I write in the 2nd, the Update button will update the rows that changed and also try to find if any row has the form "one + three". So, it will also copy data from "one" and "three" to that row. In the future if another multiname row (like :one + four or two + three) added, the button will do the same thing .

I try to update all data in the sheet by this code :

```
 Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

 Dim salesData As Range, targetRng As Range
 Dim e As Integer
 Set salesData = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2:C" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)

 If Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B2") = vbNullString Then
      Set targetRng = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A2") 'If no data in SalesDB start in row 2
 Else
      Set targetRng = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) 'If data already in SalesDB, find next free row
 End If
 salesData.Copy Destination:=targetRng
 End Sub
```

but it doesn't useful for me as:
1 Copy all data (it's time consuming and also because of "Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B2") = vbNullString" it adds data to the rest of the empty rows, not update them)

2-I can't check the value of the column B to see if there is such a field named "one + three" to update it.

At the end, don't forget that: I'm new in VBA and excel programming!!
Thank you in advance

Update 1::

```
 Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
 'here the beginning of  of your solution
 'after and instead of this line:
 'salesData.Copy Destination:=targetRng
 'try this... but carefully for the first time :)
  Dim salesData As Range, targetRng As Range
 Dim e As Integer
 Set salesData = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2:C" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)

  ' Worksheets("Sheet2").Select

 If Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B2") = vbNullString Then
      Set targetRng = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A2") 'If no data in SalesDB start in        row 2
 Else
      Set targetRng = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) 'If   data already in SalesDB, find next free row
 End If

 targetRna.Columns(3).ClearContents

Dim dataItem
Dim Found As Range
Dim rngStart As Range
Set rngStart = targetRna.Cells(1, 1)
Dim strFirstAddress As String
For Each dataItem In salesData.Columns(2).Cells

Set Found = targetRna.Find(dataItem.Value, rngStart, xlValues, xlPart)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    strFirstAddress = Found.Address

    Do
        If dataItem.Value = Found.Value Then
            Found.Offset(0, 1) = dataItem.Offset(0, 1)
        Else
            Found.Offset(0, 1) = Found.Offset(0, 1) + dataItem.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
        Set rngStart = Found

    Set Found = targetRna.Find(dataItem.Value, rngStart, xlValues, xlPart)

    If Found Is Nothing Then
        Exit Do
    ElseIf Found.Address = strFirstAddress Then
        Exit Do
    End If


    Loop
End If

Next
End Sub
```

Edit2::
()clear space in the address to see the image
![the button will affect this sheet][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ zSg1p.png

![The Update button will be here][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ sNiVK.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your:

```
salesData.Copy Destination:=targetRng
```

try to use the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'here the beginning of  of your solution
'after and instead of this line:
'salesData.Copy Destination:=targetRng
'try this... but carefully for the first time :)

targetRna.Columns(3).ClearContents

Dim dataItem
Dim Found As Range
Dim rngStart As Range
Set rngStart = targetRna.Cells(1, 1)
    Dim strFirstAddress As String
For Each dataItem In salesData.Columns(2).Cells

    Set Found = targetRna.Find(dataItem.Value, rngStart, xlValues, xlPart)

    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        strFirstAddress = Found.Address

        Do
            If dataItem.Value = Found.Value Then
                Found.Offset(0, 1) = dataItem.Offset(0, 1)
            Else
                Found.Offset(0, 1) = Found.Offset(0, 1) + dataItem.Offset(0, 1)
            End If
            Set rngStart = Found

        Set Found = targetRna.Find(dataItem.Value, rngStart, xlValues, xlPart)

        If Found Is Nothing Then
            Exit Do
        ElseIf Found.Address = strFirstAddress Then
            Exit Do
        End If


        Loop
    End If

Next
End Sub
```

**EDITED: So, once again...** I hope I didn't miss any part of your concept. I'm not sure because you writing about copy from sheet1 to sheet2 while your code copy from sheet2 to sheet1. [image][image]

And the complete code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim salesData As Range, targetRng As Range
    Dim e As Integer
    Set salesData = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1:C" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)

   If Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B2") = vbNullString Then
   Set targetRng = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2") 'If no data in SalesDB start in        row 2
   salesData.Copy Destination:=targetRng
   Exit Sub
   Else
  'if data already exists than set range to search in
  Set targetRng = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
  End If

  targetRng.Columns(3).ClearContents

   Dim boFound As Boolean
   Dim dataItem
   Dim Found As Range
   Dim rngStart As Range
   Set rngStart = targetRng.Cells(1, 1)
   Dim strFirstAddress As String
   For Each dataItem In salesData.Columns(2).Cells

          Set Found = targetRng.Find(dataItem.Value, rngStart, xlValues, xlPart)

          If Not Found Is Nothing Then
          strFirstAddress = Found.Address
          boFound = True
             Do 
               If dataItem.Value = Found.Value Then
                  Found.Offset(0, 1) = dataItem.Offset(0, 1)
               Else
                  Found.Offset(0, 1) = Found.Offset(0, 1) + dataItem.Offset(0, 1)
               End If
          Set rngStart = Found

         Set Found = targetRng.Find(dataItem.Value, rngStart, xlValues, xlPart)

         If Found Is Nothing Then
              Exit Do
         ElseIf Found.Address = strFirstAddress Then
             Exit Do
         End If
         Loop
   End If

   If Not boFound Then
          'if not found then copy into first free row
         dataItem.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3).Copy Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
   End If

   boFound = False

   Next


   End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what is "targetRna.Columns(3).ClearContents
"  and is it join two column name and then search it?? Any way it gives Error: Object required :424 error! Again thank you!

Comment: Possibly it is not full solution. I did it this way, that each time you run macro Column C in sheet 1 is cleared with `ClearContents`. Than macro search for any occurrence of B column values from 2nd sheet in 1st sheet. Both option are checke: 'one' and 'one + three' while it add values in the second situation. Try to run it with exact data you presented in your question.

Comment: Actually it doesn't highlight any line!! I will copy my whole code as update so you can check it yourself !

Comment: check new complete code. See also pictures attached. If I missed a part of your concept you would probably need to make some adjustments.

Comment: ohh!! I'm really sorry!!! It doesn't differ!! (My code made you understand in different way)! In fact  I want to copy from one sheet (master) to one another!(no matter 1 to 2 or 2 to 1) with these condition: when I click update, the program copy new values to the appropriate cell and also check for rows with 2 names (it will be needed to check only the sales column, and after find them do some calculation)! I put "+" as example and I may be need to do calculation on them, then paste them.